# AngularJS ng-if, динамическое скрытие по наличию свойств объекта

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Суть проблемы - в контроллере есть объект, обычный список свойств. По клику на стороне клиента, из объекта ремувится свойство и, когда объект полностью пуст, по директиве `ng-if` должен скрываться блок.

Пробую передать так:

```
$scope.hidden = !!Object.keys(obj).length;
```

И, соответственно, на стороне `html`:

```
ng-if="$ctrl.hidden";
```

Не срабатывает, причем никаких ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: А откуда взялось `$ctrl`? У Вас же `hidden` — это свойство непосредственно `$scope`.

Comment: $ctrl - просто использование контроллера в html, т.к. делаю через component. Можно указать $ctrl as .... но уже не стал особо заморачиваться.

Comment: Прочитай еще раз код в вопросе: присваиваешь значение скопу, а проверяешь у контроллера

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так, возможно кому-то пригодится. Просто прописал в обработчике, который удаляет свойство:

```
if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0)
      obj = null;
```

на стороне `html`

```
ng-if="$ctrl.obj"
```

разумеется, придется чуть подкорректировать код и в других обработчиках, в частности в том, который данные свойства и добавляет, но суть думаю ясна. Если кому придет в голову идея получше, буду только рад :)

Comment: На самом деле Вам нужно либо обновлять `$scope.hidden` после удаления свойства, либо в `ng-if` вызывать функцию, которая будет определена как-нибудь так: `$sciope.isHidden = function () {return !!Object.keys(obj).length;}` Суть в том, что `$scope.hidden` у вас не обновляется автоматически при изменении `obj`.

Comment: все верно, так же работает. Спасибо!